# Changing cursor after task is complete

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, cursor

I am attempting to change the mouse cursor to `Wait` before a task begins, and `Arrow` when it's completed.  However, the cursor seems to change from one to the other straight away. This is my code:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
dtResults.WriteXml(saveFileDialog.FileName);
this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
MessageBox.Show("Exporting Complete!", "Complete!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what does dtResults.WriteXml do?

Comment: @cadrell0 - It's a method contained in the DataTable class. It writes the DataTable to XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing the tasks synchronously. So, the message pump never really gets the wait cursor call as far as the user will see.

To fix this you should do this asynchronously. You can use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)since you are on .NET 4.0:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait
//Avoid any closure problems
string fileName = saveFileDialog.FileName
//Start the task of writing the xml (It will run on the next availabled thread)
var writeXmlTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>dtResults.WriteXml(fileName));
//Use the created task to attach what the action will be whenever the task returns.
//Making sure to use the current UI thread to perform the processing
writeXmlTask.ContinueWith(
    (previousTask)=>{this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;MessageBox.Show....}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: What does BeginWriteXML contain though?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using. I wrote pseudocode assuming you understood some of the async mechanisms. The version of .Net will let me know how I can show you in a little more detail

Comment: I just updated the code. I would suggest using methods for a cleaner read, but that should work. Also, read up on async and TPL as they are very handy.

Comment: I've tried the code however it's not compiling. Any idea what's wrong with the StartNew part?

Comment: If you copied and pasted verbatim, then I forgot the `s` in `TaskCreationOptions`. That should be obvious in the compiler message though

Comment: Besides that though. I changed that however it's saying that it has invalid arguments

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24720/discussion-between-justin-pihony-and-dot-net)

Comment: When you start the new task you should be starting it in a background thread and not using the UI thread (you don't even do that correctly though).  Also, the continuation *should* be run in the UI thread.

Comment: Yah, it has been a while since I wrote TPL code as I am stuck in 3.5 and misremembered the flow. It is updated and should work now...sorry for the cobwebs :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that all of this is happening on the UI thread.  Because `DataTable.WriteXml` is done synchronously, it blocks the UI and no updates are done.  This is why it will appear that the Cursor never shows as a Wait cursor.

To allow the UI to update and show the Wait cursor, you will need to move the call to `dtResults.WriteXml` to a background thread.  I recommend using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on that please? :)

Comment: @DotNET There are lots and lots of examples of how to use a BGW online.  You should be able to do some very simple research in order to find all that you need, since you have a very simple use-case and do not need to use more than the most basic of features it provides in the most commonly described manor.